# Is it possible to require files outside the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

For example, I'm developing a gem, and while I'm developing, I use `pry` instead of IRB, and `debugger` for debugging. However, I don't want possible contributors to have to install them (because they may not need them). My first idea was to put them in a Bundler group:

```
source :rubygems

gemspec

group :extras do
  gem "pry"
  gem "debugger"
end
```

And then people could use:

```
$ bundle install --without extras
```

But I want it to be a default that they're not installed. What would be perfect is that they're **not** in my `Gemfile`, but that I can still require them (if they exist on the computer). This solution would be ok because I don't care at which version they're locked. Can it be done?

Comment: just trying to understand what wrong with `bundle --without` options and then add the `.bundle` directory in git so that everytime the any other user do `bundle install` it would internally do --without

Comment: Then they can choose either to install all `:extras` or nothing. I would like them to be able to choose which gems they want to use by installing them on the disk. Maybe a contributor wants to use `pry`, but not `debugger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add arbitrary load paths and then require gems from them. Check out the global variable `$:`

```rb
puts $:.inspect
# ["/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/lib", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/vendor", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/assets", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/controllers", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/helpers", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/mailers", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/models", "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib", "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux"]
```

Now let's append to `$:` and require a gem

```rb
require 'method_source'
# LoadError: cannot load such file -- method_source
$: << '/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myset/gems/method_source-1.0.0/lib'
# ["/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/lib", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/vendor", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/assets", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/controllers", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/helpers", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/mailers", "/var/myproject/releases/20200918191637/app/models", "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib", "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux", "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myset/gems/method_source-1.0.0/lib"]
require 'method_source'
# true
```

That can be tedious if you have a lot of dependencies, though, so you might try this:

```rb
Dir['/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myset/gems/*'].each do |gem_path|
  $: << File.join(gem_path, 'lib')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`bundle install` is "opt-out"—unless you specify `--without some_group`, it installs everything.

If you absolutely don't want to have a given gem in your Gemfile, you *could* just `gem install` that rogue gem outside of your bundle. Then it'll be visible to you under `irb` and straight `ruby` (but obviously you'll get errors if you try to `require` it within code running under `bundle exec`).

Comment: This might be a helpful explanation: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/

Comment: I don't want to have them in the `Gemfile` because they're not required for development. But I would like contributors to be able to use them if they want, and that they can choose which.

So, there is no way to require gems that are not in the `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a conditional based on environment variables into the Gemfile. Example:

```
source :rubygems

gemspec

if ENV['WITH_EXTRAS'] == '1'
  gem "pry"
  gem "debugger"
end
```

The gems are then only installed/loaded, if you set the environment variable to `'1'` e.g. `WITH_EXTRAS=1 bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use the "optional" argument, and it will do exactly what you ask: it will not install the extras unless people `bundle --with extras`

```
group :extras, optional:true do
   ...
end
```

https://bundler.io/v2.3/guides/groups.html#optional-groups