# Require a gem outside the Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to require a gem temporarily that is not in Gemfile, **without altering the Gemfile**.

You can see why answers to questions such as:
[Is it possible to require files outside the Gemfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015536/is-it-possible-to-require-files-outside-the-gemfile)
[Bundler how to require gems separately in Gemfile just in one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738861/bundler-how-to-require-gems-separately-in-gemfile-just-in-one-file)

have been useless to my pursuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try if [debundle.rb](https://github.com/janlelis/debundle.rb) works for your purpose!

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for such a solution for *years*. To make a two-liner, I saved the script to my `$HOME` and `load`ed it. Charming! (Ironically, it was so I could require Pry without a rebundle)

Comment: For RSpec user: `rspec --require <debundle-path>` works for me. I need this to try [FuuBar](https://github.com/thekompanee/fuubar) locally.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/183) provides some alternatives.